# how to back port 'rotate vector by euler' to upbge fork of blender (its like blender 2.79.6 but has arctan2)

Tags: mathematics

I have code from 3x I am backporting to upbge version 2.5x (for older pcs)

I need the 'inverted' version of vector rotate in euler mode expressed as nodes in upbge 2.5x